# Multiple WebLogic instances at same address, admin console login cookie conflict

Tags: cookies, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm running three WebLogic 12 instances (different domains) in localhost, each listening a different port. When I login in one admin console, the session cookie for another gets overwritten, and I have to always re-authenticate when switching between admin consoles.

Is it possible to configure the cookie policy to avoid the conflict? And is it possible to do so with WLST in offline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to set a different cookie per domain to avoid this issue. Use the console and go to  / Configuration / General / Advanced and set the Console Cookie Name property.

Comment: Any idea how to set this value with WLST in offline mode?

Comment: I've just answered your question about it.